# New to swift not sure why this isn't working?

Tags: swift

I am trying to figure out why it won't let me mutate this value.

I am getting error: "Cannot use mutating member on immutable value: 'self' is immutable".

Any help would be appreciated. I want to increment `numberTapped` by 1.

```
func buttonAction()
{
    print("button pressed")
}

struct numTapped
{
    var numberTapped: Int
    
    init()
    {
        self.numberTapped = 0
    }
    
    mutating func increment()
    {
        numberTapped += 1
    }
    
}

struct ContentView: View
{
    var number = numTapped()
    
    var body: some View
    {
        Button(action:
                {
                    number.increment()
                    buttonAction()
                })
        {
            Text("button")
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: Hint: the immutable self is the ContentView.

Comment: Look into `@State` and `@ObservedObject`